# Number of ways in which $8$ people can be seated in a row?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Number of ways in which $8$ people can be seated in a row, if these are $4$ married couples and each couple must sit together ?

---

I got $4!*2^4$, but I don't have an answer for this.

Have I got this one right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your solution is right.

We have $2^4$ to make each pair sit and then 4! to arrange pairs.

Answer (score 1):

First arrange 4 pairs perform 4!, then interchange of male and female within pair can occur in 2 ways, here there are 4 pairs so you have to multiply 4! with 2*2*2*2, each 2 for each pair